# Determine polygon border lengths in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to determine the border lengths between features in a polygon layer. How do I do this? I want to do it for all the polygons in the layer (second image, yellow is not selection but assigned color)

[image]

[image]

Comment: get the intersection between the polygon and all the others and the call length() on the result

Comment: how do i get the intersection per polygon from a whole layer with multiple intersecting polygons?

Comment: Can you expand a bit? Is this for one selected polygon or do you want to do it for all polygons in a layer? What output do you want? A matrix of how much border of each polygon `i` is shared with polygon `j` for all polygons `i,j`, or one new field for each polygon giving the total shared border added up over all borders for that polygon?

Comment: all polygons in a layer (edited my question)

Answer (score 2):

Use the QGIS expression below to get for each polygon a list of lengths, corresponding to the length of the border it shares with each contiguos polygon.

*The expression is used here as dynamic label that generates a length value for the border of each neighbour. The red lines are added for visualization purpose with geometry genrator based on the same expression to see which lines are measured. As you can see from the comparison with the measurement tool, the expression outputs the correct length value:*
[image]

The expression to use:

```
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_touches (
            @layer, 
            boundary($geometry)
        ),
        round (
            length(
                intersection (
                    $geometry, 
                    @element
                )
            ),
            1  -- number of places to round decimals to
        )
    )
)
```